# Insert Data to DB without Page Refresh using JQuery, Inserts single rows multiple times

Tags: php, jquery

I m using jquery and php to insert data into db after fetching it from table.

However, although the insert without page refresh using jquery works fine, but it inserts the last fetched row multiple times.

*So far my code :*

**Index :**

```
<?php 
   $sqlproduct = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2";
   $resultproduct = $conn->query($sqlproduct);
   if ($resultproduct->num_rows > 0) {   
   while($rowproduct = $resultproduct->fetch_assoc()) {   
      $p_id = $rowproduct["id"];
      $p_name = $rowproduct["name"];
      $p_c_id = $rowproduct["c_id"];
      $p_v_id = $rowproduct["v_id"];
      $p_image = $rowproduct["image"];
      $p_price = $rowproduct["price"];
?>
<form action="addtocart" method="post"  id="myform">
     <input type="hidden" id="pid" name="pid" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $u_id; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="<?php echo $p_price; ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" id="vid" name="vid" value="<?php echo $p_v_id; ?>" />
         <button id='insert' class="add-cart-btn">
              <i class="icon-basket"></i>
         </button>
</form>
<?php } } else { } ?> 

<script>
        $("form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post(
                'addtocart.php',
                {
                    pid: $("#pid").val(),
                    uid: $("#uid").val(),
                    vid: $("#vid").val(),
                    quantity: $("#quantity").val(),
                    price: $("#price").val()
                },
                function(result){
                    if(result == "success"){
                        $("#result").val("Values Inserted");
                    } else {
                        $("#result").val("Error");
                    }
                }
           );
        });
    </script>
```

**addtocart.php**

```
<?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USERNAME', 'username');
    define('PASSWORD','password');
    define('DB','dbname');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

    $p_id = $_POST['pid'];
    $u_id = $_POST['uid'];
    $v_id = $_POST['vid'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    $sql = "insert into cart (p_id, u_id, v_id, price, quantity) values ('$p_id','$u_id','$v_id','$price','$quantity')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        echo 'success';
    }
?>
```

I understand that it has something to do with LIMIT and OFFSET i used to fetch product details.

I even tried altering the ID values inside HTML form and the script #id's

*Form fields*

```
<input type="hidden" id="pid<?php echo $p_id;?>" name="pid" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="uid<?php echo $p_id;?>" name="uid" value="<?php echo $u_id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="quantity<?php echo $p_id;?>" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="price<?php echo $p_id;?>" name="price" value="<?php echo $p_price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="vid<?php echo $p_id;?>" name="vid" value="<?php echo $p_v_id; ?>" />
```

*And Script ID's*

```
pid<?php echo $p_id;?>: $("#pid<?php echo $p_id;?>").val(),
uid<?php echo $p_id;?>: $("#uid<?php echo $p_id;?>").val(),
vid<?php echo $p_id;?>: $("#vid<?php echo $p_id;?>").val(),
quantity<?php echo $p_id;?>: $("#quantity<?php echo $p_id;?>").val(),
price<?php echo $p_id;?>: $("#price<?php echo $p_id;?>").val()
```

This time, it didn't even passed the values to addtocart page.

OR

*JavaScript code find the element within the context*

```
<script>
        $("form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post(
                'addtocart.php',
                {
                    pid: $(this).find("input[name='pid']").val(),
                    uid: $(this).find("input[name='uid']").val(),
                    vid: $(this).find("input[name='vid']").val(),
                    quantity: $(this).find("input[name='quantity']").val(),
                    price: $(this).find("input[name='price']").val()
                },
                function(result){
                    if(result == "success"){
                        $("#result").val("Values Inserted");
                    } else {
                        $("#result").val("Error");
                    }
                }
           );
        });
    </script>
```

This time, it didn't even passed the values to addtocart page.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You are using `form` inside `while`. Resulting in Multiple `forms`. Can you check the Source Code?

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Try adding `form` before `while`. And as @CBroe said, you should not have multiple `ID` in a HTML Doc.

Comment: When you use `id` selectors like: `$("#pid")` and you are re-using those `id` values in your HTML, specifically which element do you expect to get the value for and why?

Comment: @David i understand that while using id we need to make sure that they stay inside the loop so that for the next iteration id value changes. But when i move the script inside the loop, the whole page refreshes, which kinda not suppose to happen.

Comment: Who said anything about moving the script into the loop? That makes little sense to begin with. Your JS stays _outside_ of the loop, but you need to re-write it, so that it selects the correct elements that belong to the current form. Use a class to select these elements instead of an ID, and go read up on how to use the `context` parameter of `$(…)`. (Or use `find` instead, to select the elements under the current form element, which you can access via `$(this)` inside your event handler.)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML elements are re-using the same `id` values.  So when you select an element by that `id`, such as here:

```
$("#pid").val()
```

You're trying to target multiple elements, by what is supposed to be a unique identifier, and get back a single value.  Logically that can't work, and is against HTML standards so the behavior is undefined.

For your current setup, where each iteration of the loop has its own form, you don't need the `id` values and can just target the form elements by name.  For example, remove the `id` from each element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $p_id; ?>" />
```

And in the JavaScript code find the element within the context of the submitting form:

```
$(this).find("input[name='pid']").val()
```

Or you may even just be able to serialize the form, if the element names all match what you need.  Something like this:

```
$.post('addtocart.php',
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(result) {
        //...
});
```

Comment: Will it be something like this..


`pid: $(this).find("input[name='pid']").val() `

on the script..?

Comment: @NavKiran: Tha't what this answer suggests, yes.  Alternatively, you may also be able to just use jQuery's `.serialize()` on the form element and not have to target individual elements in the first place.

Comment: I tried `$(this).find("input[name='pid']").val()` and replace the id's in script with respective, it is not even posting the data to db now.. 

I have updated the question with this possible solution, can you check once and let me know where i did wrong.

Comment: @NavKiran: In the updated question it looks like you also made other changes.  This is probably a good time to stop changing random things and start debugging.  What is the current complete state of the code?  When the page renders in the browser, what is the client-side HTML?  In your browser's debugging tools, when the AJAX request is made (observable in the network tab), what is the data in that request?  What is the server's response?  Are there any JavaScript errors in the browser's debugging console?